# Visualise the bifurcation diagram

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

Can anyone help me visualise the bifurcation diagram that would be produced by

1. $\dot x = (x−μ)(1+μ−x^2)$

and

2. $\dot x = (μ^2−1)(μ−2)−x$

I know for 2. there is only one equilibrium point so should this give me a wave like graph?

I know for 1. I have 3 solutions so is this a pitchfork bifurcation plot?

Comment: Do you perchance mean $\dot x = (x - \mu)(1 + \mu - x^2)$ etc.?  Usually we refer to a bifurcation as occurring in a family of differential equations, not in a function.  Cheers!

Comment: Is there any constraint on $\mu$?

Comment: Yes I mean dx/dt sorry. @RobertLewis

Comment: And μ is and element of the reals! @AlessioDV

Comment: OK, I edited your post to reflect same.

Answer (score 3):

First take the second dynamical system, which is simpler than the first. We have
$$
\dot x = (\mu^2-1)(\mu-2) -x,\quad \mu\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
For every $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ we have the stationary point $x_\star = (\mu^2-1)(\mu-2)$, that is also (aymptotically) stable. In this case there is no bifurcation.

---

Concerning
$$
\dot x = (x-\mu)(1+\mu-x^2)
$$
I essentially follow the local bifurcation analysis presented in Glendinning, Chapter 8. Let $G(x,\mu) = (x-\mu)(1+\mu-x^2)$. For every $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ we have the stationary point $x_\star = \mu$, whereas the quadratic part gives $x_{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{1+\mu}$ for $\mu\geq -1$. Note that for $\mu=-1$ we have a single stationary point $x=0$.

To undesrtand the local bifurcation, start considering $(x,\mu)=(0,-1)$: since $G(0,-1)=G_x(0,-1)=0$, $G_\mu(0,-1)=1\neq 0$ and $G_{xx}(0,-1)=-2<0$ we have a saddlenode bifurcation from $x=0$ when $\mu=-1$, and since $G_\mu(0,-1) G_{xx}(0,-1)<0$ we have that the upper stationary point is stable and the lower is unstable.

Now note that if $\mu=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=: \mu_-$ then $x_-=\mu_-$, and that if $\mu=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=: \mu_+$ then $x_+=\mu_+$. In these two cases one of the two stationary points given by the quadratic part coincides with $x_\star$, thus we have two other bifurcations to study.

- If $(x,\mu)=(x_+,\mu_+)$ then
  $G(x_+,\mu_+)=G_x(x_+,\mu_+)=G_\mu(x_+,\mu_+)=0$,
  $G_{xx}(x_+,\mu_+)=-4x_->0$ and $G_{\mu
     x}(x_+,\mu_+)^2-G_{xx}(x_+,\mu_+)G_{\mu\mu}(x_+,\mu_+)>0$, thus we
  have a transcritical bifurcation for $\mu=\mu_-$. Furthermore, since
  $G_{xx}(x_+,\mu_+)=(2x_--1)^2>0$ we have that the upper stationary
  point is unstable and the lower one is stable.
- An analogous computation shows that there is a transcritical
  bifurcation for $\mu=\mu_+$, with the upper stationary points that is
  stable and the lower one that is unstable.

Remark. You can also plot the graph of $G(x,\mu)$ in the (,˙) plane and infer the stability of the equilibrium points from here.

The resulting bifurcation diagram turns out to be

[image].